# Consistent estimator of sum of squared sample covariances

Tags: covariance, estimation

This following paper made the following statement without giving proof.
https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjss/35/2/35_2_251/_pdf/-char/ja

$$a^{20}=\frac{n}{p(n+2)}\sum_{i=1}^{p}s_{ii}^2$$
$$\alpha^{20}=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sigma_{ii}^2$$

$s_{ii}$ is the sample variance and $\sigma_{ii}$ is the population variance.

Under normality of data that generated the sample covariance $S$, $a^{20}$ is a consistent estimator for $\alpha^{20}$.

I'm not sure how to derive the distribution and/or prove the consistency of $a^{20}$.